# How to quickly format programming codes in the GitHub's Issue?

Tags: github

If I create an issue with some codes in the gitHub, how to format it?

I have to add more white spaces again and again......

Is there anything like what we can see in the StackOverFlow by clicking "Code Sample" button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply wrap the code with the [fenced code block delimiters](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/).

````
```
here is
the
code
block
```
````

You can also specify a language.

````
```ruby
puts "hello"
```
````